# .Net Core React SPA routing issues when app is published

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, .net-core, single-page-application

I have a .net core 2.2 SPA using react for the front end. On the react side i'm making a GET call to the backend simply using an href.

```
<a href={`http://localhost:5004/api/Reports?team=${this.state.teamName}&project=${this.state.projectName}`} class="button">Submit</a>
```

When I debug the application from visual studio the routing is handled correctly and it calls the backend controller and downloads a file.

When I publish the application as a self contained exe it seems that the react application is intercepting the route so it displays the SPA Fallback url when the button is clicked, and when I try to make that api call directly in the browser.

I've tried removing the MapSpaFallbackRoute section from app.UseMVC as well as passing the full URL and Partial, either way it does not route correctly to the controller.

Here is the routing in the startup

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
        routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
          name: "spa-fallback",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
      });
```

As well as the UseSpa section

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
      {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
          spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
      });
```

What would cause the routing to behave differently when published vs running it through visual studio?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually) question and its answers.

Answer (score 0):

So I stumbled upon a very similar problem to this. I was developing an ASP.NET Core / ReactJS app using VS2019. When developing, everything worked fine with regards to calling the .NET API backend, but when I deployed to production, navigating to the routes of the API calls in the browser caused the React app to be returned and not the API calls. If I did a hard reload on these pages in the browser, the API responses would be returned and not the React application.

I resolved this issue by removing a call to registerServiceWorker that was included in the React / JS portion of the project by default. I was able to check for the presence of the service work by using the browser developer tools (F12) and selecting the Application tab.

Comment: in my case it was the stupid serviceworker. i removed the register method call from my index and the routing now works fine. its been causing more issues than benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I figured out that my API had issues to start on the IIS. So the requests to /api were not resolved and fallback to React app. I fixed the API issues and now /api are hitting the controller.

So make sure to fix any API issues and the controller server is up.